# How to store employee object in SQLite Database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have create a Employee object, in that properties are name,lastname,phone etc..

Now i created object

> Employee emp = new Employee();

Now i want store emp object into bytes in a SQLite in an andriod.

Please help me how to acheive?

I know how to insert values through ContentValues but I don't want to create a table with 50 cols. I just want to save the class Object and 
I want to retrieve it later.

Comment: show what you have tried so far...

Comment: try some examples on sqlite.

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/spacecowboy/AndroidTutorialContentProvider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the json of your objects. it is so easy and you can use liberaries such as [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to map your `Employee` class. You have a many options:

- [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).
- [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/).
- [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/).
- [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/).

As an example, I will show how to work with ORMLite to map your objects.

Add the Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
}
```

Map your entity Employee:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String firstName;

    @DatabaseField
    private String lastName;

    @DatabaseField
    private int phoneNumber;

    /**
     * Add here the other attributes of the entity. Then, add the get and set methods.
     */

}
```

Create your ORM Helper:

```
public class OrmLiteHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your_app_name.db";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static OrmLiteHelper mInstance = null;

    public OrmLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            // TODO: Add all your entities here, to create the tables.
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Employee.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            // TODO: Add all your entities here, to drop and recreate then.
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Employee.class, true);
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static OrmLiteHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new OrmLiteHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao getRuntimeDao(Class model) {
        return getRuntimeExceptionDao(model);
    }

}
```

To access your database data, create a DAO for the entity:

```
RuntimeExceptionDao<Employee, Integer> employeeDao = OrmLiteHelper.getInstance(context).getRuntimeDao(Employee.class);
```

Now is easy to persist the entity:

```
employeeDao.createOrUpdate(employee);
```

And even easier to retrieve your entity:

```
List<Employee> results = employeeDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("firstName", "employee_name").query();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be able to serialize your object into a byte stream and then recreate your object from a byte stream.

Then, just store that byte stream in your db.